# How to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 8080

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tomcat, port-forwarding

Currently, in a local system there is Apache Tomcat on port 8080 and Apache 2 on port 80. I'm unable to start both the servers at the same time. We need to stop apache2 to have tomcat running in the localhost. What should I do to direct the traffic coming to port 80 to port 8080, so that I can use both the servers at the same time in localhost.

Comment: What is the problem with running both servers at once? There should be no problem with running Apache and Tomcat on the same server.

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem, having apache and tomcat running at the same time is a common situation.

Comment: @UwePlonus I want the traffic coming to port 80 directed to port 8080

Answer (score 2):

Even if this does not solve your real problem (running both Apache and Tomcat on the same server) you can redirect the port with

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you dont need redirect any.
Can edit server.xml to create 2 connectors....

fe.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an iptables rule you could use to do that:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

However, it doesn't solve the problem of both services trying to listen on port 80, or redirect requests on port 80 to whichever server depending on the user's intent.  It just redirects (all inbound eth0 TCP port 80) traffic.

Comment: This really doesn't help the OP run applications on both ports. Think about it. No traffic is going to arrive at port 80 so anything listening will hear silence.

Comment: His question was "What should I do to direct the traffic coming to port 80 to port 8080, so that I can use both the servers at the same time in localhost." The question is not clear to me but this is a way to redirect TCP traffic from port 80 to port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

nat table:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
```

mangle table:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x64/0xffffffff
```

filter table:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j ACCEPT
```

This is the correct way for dealing with DPNAT "redirects" for localhost.

Answer (score -1):

Also, I think you can use Apache2 as a reverse proxy to access Tomcat.

Comment: The OP says he can't run Apache and Tomcat at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in your server.xml of apache server .. works flawlessly

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

As mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/688537/3038

Comment: Please do not copy answers given by others without [attribution](/help/referencing).